# Are the two riders of the fourth horse in Revelation 6:7-8 kings of Egypt and Cush?

Tags: revelation, isaiah

YLT Revelation 6:7-8

> ...
>
> And when he opened the fourth seal, I heard the voice of the fourth living creature saying, 'Come and behold!'
>
> and I saw, and lo, a pale horse, and he who is sitting upon him -- his name is Death, and Hades doth follow with him, and there was given to them authority to kill, (over the fourth part of the land,) with sword, and with hunger, and with death, and by the beasts of the land.
>
> ...

In Isaiah 28:14-22, there is an implication that Israel's trust in other nations was like trusting in death and hell.

> ...
>
> Therefore, hear a word of Jehovah, ye men of scorning, Ruling this people that is in Jerusalem.
>
> Because ye have said: '**We have made a covenant with death, And with Sheol we have made a provision**, An overflowing scourge, when it passeth over, Doth not meet us, Though we have made a lie our refuge, And in falsehood have been hidden.'
>
> Therefore, thus said the Lord Jehovah: 'Lo, I am laying a foundation in Zion, A stone -- a tried stone, a corner stone precious, a settled foundation, He who is believing doth not make haste.
>
> And I have put judgment for a line, And righteousness for a plummet, And sweep away doth hail the refuge of lies, And the secret hiding-place do waters overflow.
>
> **And disannulled hath been your covenant with death, And your provision with Sheol doth not stand**, An overflowing scourge, when it passeth over, Then ye have been to it for a treading-place.
>
> From the fulness of its passing over it taketh you, For morning by morning it passeth over, By day and by night, And it hath been only a trembling to consider the report.
>
> For shorter hath been the bed Than to stretch one's self out in, And the covering hath been narrower Than to wrap one's self up in [your attempts to secure peace through other powers will fall short].
>
> For as at mount Perazim rise doth Jehovah, As at the valley in Gibeon He is troubled, To do His work -- strange is His work, And to do His deed -- strange is His deed.'
>
> And now, show not yourselves scorners, Lest strong be your bands, For a consumption, that is determined, I have heard, by the Lord, Jehovah of Hosts, Is for all the land.
>
> ...

God chides Israel in Isaiah 30:1-5 for trusting in Egypt:

> Wo to apostate sons, The affirmation of Jehovah! To do counsel, and not from Me, And to spread out a covering, and not of My spirit, So as to add sin to sin.
>
> **Who are walking to go down to Egypt, And My mouth have not asked, To be strong in the strength of Pharaoh, And to trust in the shadow of Egypt [Cush?].**
>
> **And the strength of Pharaoh Hath been to you for shame, And the trust in the shadow of Egypt confusion**,
>
> For in Zoan were his princes, And his messengers reach Hanes.
>
> All he made ashamed of a people that profit not, Neither for help, not for profit, But for shame, and also for reproach!
>
> ...

Are kings of Egypt and Cush the two riders of the fourth horse in Revelation 6:7-8?

Comment: There is only one rider with a single name (singular) "death and Hades".  That is, one rider with a compound name.  The grammar does not allow for two riders.

Comment: What should "Hades doth follow with him" be then?

Comment: @Jack: Hades or the underworld is the realm of the dead, where death reigns supreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "follow" is the Greek verb, "akoutholeo"; and it forms an interesting pattern in the book of Revelation.

6:8     A: Pale horse, rider named death, hades follows, kill by sword

14:4        B: The saints follow the Lamb wherever He goes

14:8            C: The second angel follows the first

14:9            C: The third angel follows the second

14:13       B: The deeds of the saints follow them

19:14   A: White horse followed by armies of heaven - sword comes from mouth.

Note that in Rev 14:13 - "deeds" follow the saints.  That is, the effect of the saints' activity is their deeds.  The rider of the 4th house named "death" would naturally have hades (the mythical realm/place of the dead in Greek mythology) would follow.  Further, note that the word for sword (Greek "rhomphaia") is the same in Rev 1:16, 2:12, 16, 19:15, 21 as in Rev 6:8 and Luke 2:35 (as distinct from the "marchaira" in Rev 6:4, 13:10, 14 and Matt 10:34 etc).

Thus, Hades following the 4th house does not mean that another rider is present but that the effect of the activity of the 4th rider is hades following.

Comment: The reference to 14:13 is what sold it. Great answer.

Comment: So does this horseman represent a king of Egypt then? Should I ask that as another question? I think what I referenced in Isaiah still stands.

Comment: @Jack - That would be a great topic of further discussion.

Comment: [Asked](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34935/is-the-rider-of-the-4th-horse-in-revelation-67-8-a-king-of-egypt).